# Table 'django_migrations' already exists after dropping database

Tags: django, mariadb, django-database

I recently had a database issue so I decided to nuke it since I had no important data. I deleted my migrations folder in my app directory and dropped the database. However now when I go to recreate everything with `manage.py migrate` I get the following error:

```
  File "../manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "../manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 234, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 91, in migrate
    self.recorder.ensure_schema()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 69, in ensure_schema
    raise MigrationSchemaMissing("Unable to create the django_migrations table (%s)" % exc)
django.db.migrations.exceptions.MigrationSchemaMissing: Unable to create the django_migrations table ((1050, "Table 'django_migrations' already exists"))
```

I have tried running this after deleting the database, and after recreating the empty database. I can be 100% sure there are no tables there right now. So I have no idea why it thinks that table is there.

Comment: delete migration and '__pycache__' folder, drop database. Then run makemigrations for all app and then migrate it

Comment: @Sachin Singh This does not fix the issue but rather resets everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured out my issue. MariaDB had my tables open in the cache. I ran two statements: `FLUSH QUERY CACHE;` and `FLUSH TABLES;`. I'm not sure which one did the trick but I was then able to run migrations and everything works again now!

Comment: It was `FLUSH TABLES;`.

Answer (score 0):

Removed migrations and created the project directory and startapp directory again.
Then makemigration and migrate.  Worked on mySQL.